# Problem binding data to view from web api in Angular

Tags: angular

I have my data binding which is coming in from a web API and I am binding that to my view, however one field is causing a problem because it has a dot in the middle of the name `desc_ci.serial_number`, I am trying the following code so far:

**API data structure from API**

```
desc_ci.serial_number: "cxxxxxxxx"
description: ""
etc etc
```

**html**

```
<span class="text-gray">{{receivedIncident.desc_ci.serial_number}}</span>
```

**.ts file**

```
receivedIncident: any;


  constructor(private service: nowService,
    private appComponent: AppComponent,
    private userService: UserService,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.receivedIncident = { number: '', opened_at: '', description: '', short_description: '', desc_ci.serial_number: ''}; this.receivedLocation = {city:null, country: null}
  }

private getIncident() {
    this.service.getIncident(this.s_id, this.c_id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Result - ', data);
      console.log('incident data is received');
      this.loading = true;
      this.receivedIncident = data.result[0];

    })
  }
```

I am getting errors: Cannot find the name 'desc_ci'??

Any ideas?

Comment: That is malformed json. The name should be quoted if there are illegal property name character. Example: `"desc_ci.serial_number" : "value"`. Your code also needs to reference it correctly which you can do using a property indexer `{{receivedIncident['desc_ci.serial_number']}}`

Comment: how about binding that to the view?

Comment: That worked fine, could submit answer and I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible problems.

1. That is malformed json. The name should be quoted if there are illegal property name character. Example: `"desc_ci.serial_number" : "value"`.
2. Your code also needs to reference it correctly which you can do using a property indexer `{{receivedIncident['desc_ci.serial_number']}}`.